# Kendo Datepicker selected value is not refreshing or sent to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo datepicker for selecting date.
I am using
@HTML.TextBoxFor(c=>c.TestDate, new{@id="txtTestDate"} as HTML helper tag.

for fetching the datepicker control, using below script

$("#txtTestDate").kendoDatePicker();

all values are submitted using @html.beginform(). there is no ajax or any other calls to controller method

I have a future date validation, where future dates cannot be selected. after i get validation error, if i select back today's date in kendo datepicker, its sending the value as 1-1-0001 as input and code behind, textbox for value is remaining as 1-1-0001, even if we change/select the new value from datepicker control.

please help me resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: To fetch the date, try this query :   

$("#txtTestDate").data("kendoDatePicker");

Comment: Hi @Vinoth.R, i am using form submit for sending values to controller. model binding the values. but the problem is with kendo datepicker, its not refreshing the values